# What is the difference between C.x and cls.x in a @classmethod?

Tags: python, python-3.x, static-methods, class-method

Following code supposed:

```
class C:
    x = 0

    @classmethod
    def increment1(cls):
        cls.x += 1

    @classmethod
    def increment2(cls):
        C.x += 1

    @staticmethod
    def increment3():
        C.x += 1
```

Is there any difference between the methods `increment1`, `increment2` and `increment3`?

Comment: Consider what happens if you subclass C.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thx for the hint. Is it the only difference? So, there is no difference between `increment2` and `increment3`?